# Formatting displayed data in Multiline Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am novice coder in C# and I am currently working with a report generator. I am reading data from a text file and displaying the results in multi-line textbox.  I am currently having issues with formatting the data so it will look neat and professional. I am adding string with spaces for separation but its making the data look uneven.

Is there away to display the data in the multi-line textbox just as the picture below shows? Also, is there away to populate the multi-line textbox with titles when the form is started?

[image]

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static string newLine = Environment.NewLine;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {

        double grandtotal = 0.0;
        int totalcount = 0;


        string space2 = "          ";
        string space3 = "                    ";

        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        grandtotal += totalSales[i];
            totalcount += count[i];
         }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        textBox1.AppendText( "Product Name" + space2 + "Total Sales" + space3 + "Average" + newLine );

        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
            if( productName[i] != null ) {
            if( totalSales[i] != 0 ) {
                textBox1.AppendText( productName[i] + space3 
                + totalSales[i] + space3 
                + ( totalSales[i] / count[i] ).ToString( "#.##" ) + newLine );
                }
         }
    }

        textBox1.AppendText( "Grand Total" + space3 + grandtotal 
        + space3 + ( grandtotal / totalcount ).ToString( "#.##" ) + newLine );



        }
    }



    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a windows application or asp.net application?

Comment: @RajatSaini windows application

Comment: you better use VS Reports, Crystal Reports like reporting tools or use html report and display them in browser control

Comment: Is it a requirement that you display the results in a multiline textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.Format method.

Here is link that can guide you http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format.